# SyntaxError: Unexpected token z in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, fetch

Доброе утро. При отправки post запроса на сервер, возникает следующая ошибка на стороне сервера `SyntaxError: Unexpected token z in JSON at position 0` [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

буква соответственно меняется на первую, из выпадающего списка.

файлик `main.js` откуда идет запрос

```
showRegionsBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let inputValue = input.value;
    console.log(inputValue)
    // request options
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        body: inputValue,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
    console.warn(options)
    // send post request
    fetch("/sendRegion", options)
        .then(async response => {
            
            try {
                const data = await response.json()
                console.log('response data?', data)
              } catch(error) {
                console.log('Error happened here!')
                console.warn(error)
                // console.error(error)
              } }  )  
})
```

файлик `app.js`, где запрос обрабатывается.

```
app.post('/sendRegion', async  (req, res, next)=>{
  console.log("sendRegion пришел")
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

Главный вопрос почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: а вы json отправляете?

Comment: Да, я пытался и весь options в  JSON.stringify() сделать, всеравно не очень вышло.